# Why I reload model and continue training the loss raise rapidly?

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

here's a similar [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42029046/tensorflow-batch-loss-spikes-when-restoring-model-for-training-from-saved-checkp), but I think `torch` is good enough to deal with initialization problem.

---

Let's see loss first

```
# first time save and the loss  
epoch:8  loss:2.6038

# second time reload, and save model when epoch is 10
epoch:8  loss:7.8922
epoch:10 loss:4.8546

# third time reload, and save model when epoch is 27
epoch:10 loss:6.0920
epoch:27 loss:2.1613

# fourth time reload and training
epoch:27 loss:6.0920
```

as you can see, once I reload the model and run a epoch training, the loss raising instead of descending. It's really strange.

I use `step` method that because of my machine cannot support big batch.

1. The first time I use four GPU with **16 batch size** and backward the loss every **2 step.**.
2. The second time I use two GPU with **8 batch size** and backward the loss every **4 step**
3. The third time I use four GPU with **16 batch size** and backward the loss every **2 step.**.
4. The fourth time I use four GPU with **16 batch size** and backward the loss every **2 step.**.

According to the first to the third time, I think it's `batchnorm` problem cause the batch size is different that the param `alpha` and `beta` is not suitable for another set.

But surprisingly, the fourth time still get a similar situation.So it's really confuse me.Did I miss some param should save? Here's my load and reload code.

```py
# saving script 
    def save_model(self, path, epoch, model, optimizer):
        #if epoch % 4 != 0:
        #    return
        if isinstance(model, torch.nn.DataParallel):
            state_dict = model.module.state_dict()
        else:
            state_dict = model.state_dict()
        torch.save({
            'epoch': epoch,
            'model_state_dict': state_dict,
            'optimizer_state_dict': optimizer.state_dict(),
            'learning_rate':optimizer.state_dict()['param_groups'][0]['lr']
            # 'loss': loss
        }, path)
```

```py
# reloading script 
    def load_model(self, model, optimizer, resume, strict=True):
        checkpoint = torch.load(resume, map_location=lambda storage, loc: storage)
        print('loaded weights from {}, epoch {}'.format(resume, checkpoint['epoch']))
        state_dict_ = checkpoint['model_state_dict']
        state_dict = {}
        for k in state_dict_:
            if k.startswith('module') and not k.startswith('module_list'):
                state_dict[k[7:]] = state_dict_[k]
            else:
                state_dict[k] = state_dict_[k]
        model_state_dict = model.state_dict()
        if not strict:
            for k in state_dict:
                if k in model_state_dict:
                    if state_dict[k].shape != model_state_dict[k].shape:
                        print('Skip loading parameter {}, required shape{}, ' \
                              'loaded shape{}.'.format(k, model_state_dict[k].shape, state_dict[k].shape))
                        state_dict[k] = model_state_dict[k]
                else:
                    print('Drop parameter {}.'.format(k))
            for k in model_state_dict:
                if not (k in state_dict):
                    print('No param {}.'.format(k))
                    state_dict[k] = model_state_dict[k]
        model.load_state_dict(state_dict, strict=False)
        optimizer.load_state_dict(checkpoint['optimizer_state_dict'])
        for state in optimizer.state.values():
            for k, v in state.items():
                if isinstance(v, torch.Tensor):
                    state[k] = v.cuda()
        epoch = checkpoint['epoch']
        # loss = checkpoint['loss']
        return model, optimizer, epoch
```

Comment: Why don't you just `model_state_dict`, what is the point of creating `state_dict` like that? Are you sure there are no errors as the variables names for loaded `state_dict` and the thing you're trying to create are almost the same. Also you could explicitly use `module.eval()` and `module.train()` before and after restoring to rule that out.

Comment: In somehow the `torch.save` cannot save the right module name.for example there is error: 
'Missing key(s) in state_dict: "module.base_network.conv1.weight",Unexpected key(s) in state_dict: "base_network.conv1.weight"'

actually it's just the module.name problem, so I create a `state_dict`. And I am sure using `model.eval()` and `model.train()` about what you said .